# How would I work around this invalid literal for int() with base 10 error?

Tags: python, literals, valueerror

```
import math

# The standard gravitational parameter for the sun
mu = 1.327 * math.pow(10, 20)

class Planet:
  def __init__(self, name, radius, moons, orbital_radius):
    self.name = name
    self.radius = radius
    self.moons = moons
    self.orbital_radius = orbital_radius

  def collide(self):
    self.moons = self.moons + 1
    return self.moons


def volume(Planet):
  v = (4 / 3) * math.pi * math.pow(Planet.radius, 3)
  return str(v)

def surface(Planet):
  area = 4 * math.pi * math.pow(Planet.radius, 2)
  return str(area)  

def physical(Planet):
  if Planet.moons == 1:
    Planet.moons = str(Planet.moons) + " moon"
  else:
    Planet.moons = str(Planet.moons) + " moons"
  return (Planet.name + " has a volume of " + volume(Planet) + " cubic km, a surface area of " + surface(Planet) + " sq. km, and " + Planet.moons)

def dynamic(Planet):
  period = 2 * math.pi * Planet.orbital_radius * math.sqrt(Planet.orbital_radius / mu)
  return (Planet.name + " has a year of approximately " + str(period // (60 * 60 * 24)) + " days")

Earth = Planet('Earth', 6371, 1, 1.496 * math.pow(10, 11))
Jupiter = Planet('Jupiter', 69911, 79, 7.786 * math.pow(10, 11))

print(physical(Earth))
print(physical(Jupiter))
print(dynamic(Earth))
print(dynamic(Jupiter))

print(Earth.collide())
```

I understand that self.moons is turned into a string due to the physical function but how would I go about in turning into an integer again. It doesn't seem possible as an integer and string is stored as its value that's why I'm getting the error message `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 moon'` when I attempt to `print(Earth.collide())`

Comment: Why store the string back on the planet instance? Don't replace `Planet.moons`, just format a string.

Comment: Otherwise, just split off the `moon`/`moons` string: `int(instance.moons.partition(" ")[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just partition the string on a space and take the first part:

```
int(self.moon.partition(" ")[0])
```

You can also use `str.split()` but partition is a little faster for the 'only need to split once' case.

The *better* approach is to not set the `.moons` attribute to a string. Keep it an integer, there is no need to replace it just to format a nice string with information:

```
def physical(Planet):
    if Planet.moons == 1:
        moons = str(Planet.moons) + " moon"
    else:
        moons = str(Planet.moons) + " moons"
    return (Planet.name + " has a volume of " + volume(Planet) + " cubic km, a surface area of " + surface(Planet) + " sq. km, and " + moons)
```

You may want to look at [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) or the [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
def physical(Planet):
    moons = f"{Planet.moons} moon"
    if Planet.moons != 1:
        moons += 's'
    return (
        f"{Planet.name} has a volume of {volume(Planet)} cubic km, a surface "
        f"area of {surface(Planet)} sq. km, and {moons}"
    )
```

Either way, by using a local variable `moons` to contain the formatted *number of moons* value, you don't alter the `Planet.moons` value so don't have to worry about how to go back to it being an integer again.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, to stick with a local/private variable in `def physical(Planet)`, because it is not used anywhere else and just a format to a value.

```
def physical(Planet):
  if Planet.moons == 1:
    _planet_moons = str(Planet.moons) + " moon"
  else:
    _planet_moons = str(Planet.moons) + " moons"
  return (Planet.name + " has a volume of " + volume(Planet) + " cubic km, a surface area of " + surface(Planet) + " sq. km, and " + _planet_moons)
```

This prevents you from convering the value forth and back.

Comment: Local variables are already 'private', there is no need to name them with an underscore at the start.